# Why I can't run struts2.5.13 in jdk9 win10

Tags: java, struts2

I followed the official tutorial,http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html. But always throw exception when i run webapp.I tried many times but I really don't know how to reslove it.

Here is exception

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\D:\.m2\repository\org\apache\struts\struts2-core\2.5.13\struts2-core-2.5.13.jar
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
at java.base/java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2300)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:951)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:216)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:324)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:295)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:234)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JarEntryRevision.needsReloading(JarEntryRevision.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.fileNeedsReloading(DefaultFileManager.java:62)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:425)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.needReloadContainerProviders(ConfigurationManager.java:208)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:174)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:960)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeStaticResourceRequest(ExecuteOperations.java:59)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

[Exception picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8O07.png)

Comment: Seems to me that the url 'jar:file:\D:\.m2\'..... is incorrect.

Comment: Seems you have wrong URL.

Comment: @Smith Could you share the pom.xml of your project as well please.

Comment: I just followed the official tutorial,so my pom.xml is the same as official

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,I know the reason.Because Struts didn't support jdk9 now.You can see issue I created.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/WW/issues/WW-4869?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `jar:` and `file:\` before the path

```
D:\.m2\repository...
```

As pointed out by Alan Bateman below, it takes a file path, not a URI.

Comment: Remove the `file:` prefix too, the JarFile constructor takes a file path, not a URI.

Comment: But i don't know how to remove it.When i run command `mvn jetty:run`, maven will done it automatically.