# InvalidPathException struts2

Tags: struts2

I use Intellj Idea (version:2017.2.4) as My Java IDE and I deployed it on Tomcat(version:9.0.1).This is a simple Struts2(version:2.5.13) project.
I deployed the project successfully and when I open index.jsp. This problem occured.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\D:\homework\struct\ideas\20171019exp3\out\artifacts\20171019exp3_war_exploded\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.5.13.jar

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\D:\homework\struct\ideas\20171019exp3\out\artifacts\20171019exp3_war_exploded\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.5.13.jar
    java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    java.base/java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2300)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:951)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:216)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
    java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:324)
    java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:295)
    java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:234)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JarEntryRevision.needsReloading(JarEntryRevision.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.fileNeedsReloading(DefaultFileManager.java:62)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:425)
    org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.needReloadContainerProviders(ConfigurationManager.java:208)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:174)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:960)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeStaticResourceRequest(ExecuteOperations.java:59)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:130)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
```

It said that there're something wrong with the Struts2's lib.But I got them from the offical website of Struts2.
I don't now what's wrong. Help me plz.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I can't run struts2.5.13 in jdk9 win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643827/why-i-cant-run-struts2-5-13-in-jdk9-win10)

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in Struts 2.5.14. Please see [this jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4869)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Java compatible with tomcat9.1 that is may be JDK1.8
and also use the JARS of  Struts2.0 compatible with the JDK 1.8
because when you use the incompatible JAR with JAVA, this error will aappear